# Azure Data Lake U-SQL parallel jobs failed

Tags: u-sql

we are running a u-sql job through ADF that reads a folder with a Avro file and converts the data to csv. Running simultaneous jobs, reading from different folders and outputting to different folders caused the following error

```
FinalMetadataOperationUserError: Failed to write job meta-data due to user error

Component
JobManager_User

Message
Failed to write job meta-data due to user error

Description
Version of object ddc1c212-b227-4b0b-8199-58bde69ce2e1.master.Avro doesn't exist

   at Scope.MetadataService.Client.Usql.WcfBasedMetadataClientForUsql.ExecuteMetadataJob(MetadataJob mdJob)
   at MetaDataExecutor.RealMetaDataExecutor.Execute(MetadataJob job)
   at MetaDataExecutor.Committer.Commit(MetadataJob job)

Job URL
https://***.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/jobLink/8b604ae4-179d-4375-a68a-c1b6771473ca
```

Upon checking the job resources, the 8b604ae4... folder indeeed has the Avro dll. Does anyone understand this error message or how can we setup ADF to run parallel u-sql jobs? Our pipeline is pretty straightforward as seen in the image below
                                   [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the dll in the database which your ADF is running.

So upload the dll to the ADF like "@CFG\Assemblies" and create a script to register it.

```
DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [Avro];

CREATE ASSEMBLY [Avro] FROM @"Assemblies/Avro.dll";
```

Run the script once and you will have this assembly registered in the database.

**Edit:** if you want to output to different folders make sure you are using `SET @@FeaturePreviews = "DataPartitionedOutput:on";` in your U-SQL code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Yup the assemblies are registered.  Everything works fine as long as ADF jobs aren't executed in parallel :(

Comment: @user611333 if you want partitioned outputs (for example to the job write to diferent folders) make sure you use `SET @@FeaturePreviews = "DataPartitionedOutput:on";` in your code. It is still in preview but it works. Also to run an parallel job it depends of your context. You can have an ForEach job yo do your job and change the `Batch count` to a greater number than 1.

Comment: thanks again for your response. Ah, we aren't partitioning as we are writing to different folders based on a dateTime parameter passed. I understand foreach makesthe execution iterative, but we wanted the ability to execute multiple independent instances

Comment: @user611333 yes but you can do it using forEach or Triggers.